# Question regarding Google Apps Script oAuth2 Third Party Authentification Code

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

this is my first time posting a question to stack overflow since I have an issue I cant get past.

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to extract data of my car from the "Mercedes me" platform. It's a pure hobby project.

"Mercedes me" has an API with oAuth2 verification.

I am trying to realize this in Google Sheets since I want to do calculations with the data retrieved.

Hence I started coding in Apps Script.

I am able to exchange an Authentification Code with a Token and then get data from the platform using the following code:

```
  var options = {
  headers : { Authorization: 'Basic '+ Utilities.base64Encode('Client ID:Client Secret')},
  method : 'post',
  'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  muteHttpExceptions : false,
  }
  var authorization_code = 'TGVWD9pNif1wuDBYa6fFPn4QHNW9h6_f2-kxL34V'

  var authUrl = 'https://id.mercedes-benz.com/as/token.oauth2?grant_type=authorization_code&code='+authorization_code+'&redirect_uri=https://localhost/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(authUrl, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  var token = data.access_token
  'Logger.log(token);'



var options = {
  headers : { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
  accept : 'application/json'
}


    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.mercedes-benz.com/vehicledata/v2/vehicles/<vehicle identification number>/resources/', options);    
    'var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); '
    'var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(response);'
    Logger.log(response);
```

So this is not the issue. The issue is that currently I need to manually insert the Authorization Code (as you can see in the code snippet above) which will then be exchanged with the Token by my script. The goal would be to generate the Authorization Code automatically.

I have created an authorization URL which will give me the Authorization Code when entered and opened in the Browser.
However, when I try to achieve the same in Apps Script via UrlFetchApp it will send me back some unusable html code instead of an Authorization Code.

```
function Authentification() {

var url = 'https://id.mercedes-benz.com/as/authorization.oauth2?response_type=code&client_id=a9f67f5f-cb2b-413b-9ea5-78df02b668a1&redirect_uri=https://localhost/&scope=mb:vehicle:mbdata:payasyoudrive&state=1000';

var options = {
  muteHttpExceptions : false, //theoretisch nicht notwendig
  followRedirects : true, //theoretisch nicht notwendig
  method : 'get', //theoretisch nicht notwendig
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var json = response.getHeaders;
var data = JSON.stringify(json);

Logger.log(response)


}
```

Result is some html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml><head><meta charset=utf-8><m
```

But what I am trying is to get a redirect Url like this (including the Authorization Code):

```
https://localhost/?code=DXPzKdV58t3rWlpuVmD3XT35BbL__n0auuAxL34V&state=1000
```

My assumption is, the problem is that when the link is opened by Apps Script's URLFetchApp it is never asked to enter my "Mercedes me" login credentials. Most likely I am not seing a basic OAuth logic here. Would really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The solution came to my mind in my sleep :-D

I deployed the whole thing as a webapp and used the webapp-link as the redirect uri.

After this I was able to extract the authorization code from the url with the following code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var param = e.queryString;
  param = e.parameter;
  var code = param.code;
```